# MariaDB Find Where Count() = 0

Tags: count, mariadb, is-empty

I am trying to find what days do not have an entree(recipe_course=18), but all I am getting is a zero result.  What am I missing?

```
Two tables
table recipes{recipe_id, recipe_name, recipe_course}
table meals{meal_id, meal_date, meal_recipe}

Select `meal_date`
From `meals` mls
Join `recipes` rrr on mls.`meal_recipe` = rrr.`recipe_id`
Where rrr.`recipe_course` = 18
Group by `meal_date`
Having Count(`recipe_course`) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is to use "not in". "=Find all meal dates that do not have recipe_course 18"

```
select m.meal_date
from meals m
where m.meal_recipe not in (
  select r.recipe_id
  from recipes r
  where r.recipe_course = 18
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea, and I have already explored this, but this does not work as on each day there are also other course(s)(ie bread, beverage, sides, etc) for each meal.

Comment: So how do you differentiate entree from the bread/beverage etc?

Comment: by the recipe_course which is third table that has the different courses, example:
24 = beverage
27 = desert  
30 = salad  
33 = bread

Comment: So how does for example the beverage (recipe_course 24) affect the query above? What is it in it that makes the query logic fail?

Answer (score 0):

Or, using `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL`:

```
SELECT  m.meal_date
    FROM  meals m
    LEFT JOIN  recipes r  ON r.recipe_id = m.meal_recipe
      AND  r.recipe_course = 18
    WHERE  r.recipe_id IS NULL
```

Also possible with `NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * ... )`